# Name for "slurp" animation and / or how to in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, animation

I would like to find an example of how to implement the "slurp" animation in Silverlight. This is the effect you get when you minimize apps to the dock in Mac OS X. Is there a better name for this? Google doesn't find anything useful with "slurp animation silverlight".

Comment: On macs it's called the genie effect